# Dynamic range for vlookup in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a possibility to set a dynamic range.
The problem is that Excel does not accept the typing.
Five rows of a matrix should be looked through for each a.
The vlookup is working with a fixed range such as "E43:AT47" but not for a combined one.

```
        Range_Zeile_Start = 5 * a - 12
        Range_Zeile_End = 5 * a - 8
        Range_Count = "R" & Range_Zeile_Start & "C5:R" & Range_Zeile_End & "C46"

        Fahrzeit_kk = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(1, b).Value, Range_Count, 42, False)
```

Comment: Try the formula in a separate cell.. the issue is with `Range_Count`, What is the meaning of address `R3C5:R7C46` when `a=3`? That address has no meaning. Also you are looking for column `42` while your cols are from `C:R`(?)

Comment: @bulbus - I think this is RC notation. Would be simpler if you could not use RC notation.

Comment: I agree, the issue is with range_count. For a=3 the range for vlookup should be "E3:AT7", for a=4 it should be "E8:AT12" and so on. I tried several typings to combine the range but excel didn´t accept one of those. @bulbus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set-up your Range correct.

See code below:

```
Dim VlookRng As Range

Range_Zeile_Start = 5 * a - 12
Range_Zeile_End = 5 * a - 8

' set up the Range for the Vlookup
Set VlookRng = Range(Cells(Range_Zeile_Start, 5), Cells(Range_Zeile_End, 46))
Fahrzeit_kk = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(1, b).value, VlookRng, 42, False)
```